# How to configure kubectl scale command to fail if image is wrong

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

If the current image is wrong/old/dne then I want this command to fail:

```
kubectl scale deploy gms --replicas=4
```

it just scales whatever is there - but I want it to check to ensure it's scaling the desired image:

```
kubectl scale deploy gms --replicas=4 --image="$name:$id"
```

is there a way to ensure that's scaling the desired image?